# INotifyPropertyChanged does not update Value Converter

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged, ivalueconverter

I have some properties which implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface. It works fine. But in my code I also use some value converters (if value < 3 - make grid red, if value >3 and value < 10 - make grid blue, etc.).

The problem is how to refresh value converter after **PropertyChanged** was raised?
Is there simple code behind solution?
Thanks all and sorry for my bad English!

Here some code:

```
public class NotifyColors : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Color _TodayColor;
    public Color TodayColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _TodayColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_TodayColor != value)
            {
                _TodayColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TodayColor");
            }
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            // it raised correctly when I change color with color picker control
        }
    }
}

// here is value converter
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(Brush))]
public class PositionToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    ModulePreferences ModulePrefs;
    public PositionToBackgroundConverter(ModulePreferences ModulePrefs)
    {
        this.ModulePrefs = ModulePrefs;
    }

    #region IValueConverter Member

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (ModulePrefs.UseColoringByPosition)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    short value_short = (short)value;
                    if (value_short <= 3)
                        return (Brush)new SolidColorBrush(ModulePrefs.NotifyColorsObj._TodayColor); // here is changing property
                    else
                        return (Brush)new SolidColorBrush(ModulePrefs.NotifyColorsObj.T100PlusColor);
                }
                else
                    return Brushes.Transparent;
            }
            catch
            {
                return Brushes.Transparent;
            }
        }
        else
            return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And here I apply my value converter to the grid:

```
// assign backgroundconverter
var grid = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
bin = new Binding();
bin.Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("DataItem.{0}", LastPositionColumnName));
bin.Converter = new PositionToBackgroundConverter(ProjectViewObj.ModulePrefs);
grid.SetValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty, bin);
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post some code, showing your value converter, showing the XAML binding, and the code where you raise the property.

Comment: Property change event is raised correctly (I can see it with breakpoint).

Comment: I would bet folding money that there are binding errors showing up in the Output window when you run this program in the debugger.  If you look at those errors and read them carefully, they will tell you what the binding is trying to do, which almost certainly is not the same as what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have done it "correctly" the `PropertyChanged` event will cause an update of the bindings which bind to that property, when this occurs any converters that are used in *the same binding* will reconvert the values. So normally the conversions happen on their own. If this is not the case you are probably using the converters "inappropriately", please post some code because without it it's quite impossible to tell what exactly you are doing wrong.

**Edit:** You use `grid.SetValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty, bin)`, you should use `grid.SetBinding(Grid.BackgroundProperty, bin)` instead since it is a binding.

**Edit2:** This really has nothing to do with converters.
In your sample code you bind to `IntValue`, then you change `TodayColor` and expect the binding to be updated, **not gonna happen**. If you want the binding to react to both properties you have to either use a `MultiBinding` or raise the respective events since your properties are interdependent.

i.e.

```
    private Color _TodayColor;
    public short _IntValue;

    public short IntValue
    {
        get { return _IntValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_IntValue != value)
            {
                _IntValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IntValue");
                OnPropertyChanged("TodayColor");
            }
        }
    }

    public Color TodayColor
    {
        get { return _TodayColor; }
        set
        {
            if (_TodayColor != value)
            {
                _TodayColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TodayColor");
                OnPropertyChanged("IntValue");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should specify further what exactly does not update. I also added something to the answer that might be relevant.

Comment: grid.SetBinding(Grid.BackgroundProperty, bin) - no, it no help me :( >> You should specify further what exactly does not update. When I change color with color picker it raised changing event, but backgroud of my grid is not updating. Maybe I must set some DataContex for grid?

Comment: Well, your binding needs some kind of source of course, whether the source is directly specified in the binding or if it should use the DataContext is up to you. First you should make sure that the binding works at all, because if it does not it's not quite surprising that it does not get updated either. So can you confirm that it works the first time it is applied?

Comment: When I use dinamic color in another project with xaml-code I use some trick with <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainColorBrush" Color="{Binding Path=MainColor}" /> <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MainColorBrush}" />. Maybe here I must use solidcolorbrush too? For testing my binding I tryed to bind it to another static panel, and it change background correctly.

Comment: It's no use if you can bind it to another control, after all that is not what you want. Make sure it works for that Grid.

Comment: If I bind it directly to background property with this code: Background="{Binding Path=TodayColor}" it not working :) But when I use solidcolobrush and binding with: Background="{DynamicResource MainColorBrush}" it's working :)

Comment: Then this is most likely just a binding problem which has nothing to do with converters. As Robert Rossney noted you should debug your binding using the Output-window in VS.

Comment: oh, explanation for this behaviour with solidcolorbrush is pretty simple: Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='#FFBA5A5B' BindingExpression:Path=TodayColor; DataItem='NotifyColors' (HashCode=47097466); target element is 'Grid' (Name='grid1'); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

Comment: Please look at sample project: http://www.mediafire.com/?3z9slyjz7mwytwp . Value converter does not updating :(

Comment: BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(grid1, Grid.BackgroundProperty).UpdateTarget(); - this helps, but is there another way to send update command to value converters?

Comment: Your binding is only updated if the PropertyChanged event of property in the path is fired. Most likely the property that is bound to does not change when you change the colour, if those poperties are dependent on each other you need to manually raise a PropertyChanged event for the dependent property. For example if i bind to a property `UnreadMessageCount` (which is calculated on the fly) this property is dependent on the general message count, so if the message collection is changed i need to manually raise the PropertyChanged event for the `UnreadMessageCount` property.

Comment: I understand, but PropertyChanged event for Color property is fires. Or you mean, that I must call manually PropertyChanged event for converter (sorry, my english is very bad)? On some others wpf communities peoples says, that I should rebind property, make value converter as DataClass with implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface or, finally, write BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(grid1, Grid.BackgroundProperty).UpdateTarget();. But all of them is bad idea for my solution, because my grid1 is a FrameworkElementFactory in some ControlTemplate style.

Comment: Hm, with my sample project this works perfectly, thanks. But in my original solution IntValue does not exist - this grid is binded to DataTable object. Look at original post (// assign backgroundconverter). How can I call OnPropertyChanged, if integer value for value converter is binded to datagrid DataTable object? Thanks for any your advices, it helps me to solve my problem!

Comment: If you cannot raise the event from your binding target you should use a `MultiBinding` to bind to the color as well. I suggest you accept my answer and make a new question if you have trouble with the multibinding (after searching for a solution first of course), otherwise this is getting way out of hand and i am not going to walk your through everything here.

Comment: Big thanks for your helping. I will try solve my problem with multibinding.